# Flutter Firebase-Cloud-Messaging not appearing in android emulator

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a FCM setup in my flutter app. Everything works as expected in the iOS world, but I can't get it to work in the android world. I can see the Push-Notification in the notification drawer, but they don't appear like the classic Push-Notification widget in the top bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Emulators don't have google apis servives. So use a real device which has google services installed in that device

Answer (score 0):

Android Emulators won't work. You need a physical device if you want to test cloud-messaging on Android.

Comment: For iOS Simulator, you can drag/drop a apns file to create a push notification. Does android have an equivalent workaround?